# Application crash when I insert data in textfield using this character (,"",'') in data base

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am  inserting the text field value in data base .Actually my application crash when user use (,"",'')comma single code ,double code.I think we cannot add these character in data base?
can you please tell me how to remove this character .I should only allow thise charater which don't crash the insert query. I am using sqlite in phonegap.

I found this but this is not good solution because some character allowed in data base

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".caseName_h", function () {
  if (/[^\w]/g.test($(this).val())) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/g, ""));
    PG_alert('Special characters not allowed!');
   }
 });

 function insertData() {
     db.transaction(createTable, errorCB, afterSuccessTableCreation);
 }

 //create table and insert some record
 function createTable(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName  VARCHAR(100) unique NOT NULL ,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)');

     tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');

 }
 //function will be called when an error occurred
 function errorCB(err) {
     navigator.notification.alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
 }

 //function will be called when process succeed
 function afterSuccessTableCreation() {
     console.log("success!");
     db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);
 }

 //select all from SoccerPlayer
 function getallTableData(tx) {
     // tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a");       
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
 }

 /*function querySuccess(){
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    alert(result.rows.item(0).CaseName)
        db.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM "'+result.rows.item(0).CaseName+'"', [],
   // tx.executeSql('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  b)', [],
              function(tx, results) {
               t=results.rows.length;
               alert(t)
});
    });

}

}*/

 function querySuccess(tx, result) {
     var len = result.rows.length;
     var countDoument = 0
     $('#folderData').empty();
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

         currentTableName = result.rows.item(i).CaseName;

         countElements(currentTableName, function (i) {
             return function (result_count) {
                 countDoument = result_count; // here it count value 

                 $('#folderData').append(
                     '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + '</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + countDoument + '</span>' + '</a>' +
                     '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>' + '</li>');
                 $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

             };
         }(i));
     }
 }
 tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this it will help you..

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Tab(Name, Date) VALUES(?,?)',
              [$('.caseName_h').val(),
               $('.caseDate_h').val()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You surely can insert these characters in a database, but you need to escape them.

The best way is to use PDO's prepared queries, where you can define elements inside the query by indicators like "?" or :value, then put the contents in the PDO->execute($args) method.

Not allowing special characters in such case is not user friendly, as either them or you may need to insert such characters.

I recommand you to first check how you send the informations to the database. Can you show us how you make your requests to the db ?

Comment: Hi i am sending like this .check my update..

Comment: I am inserting the data on casetable .the value of $('.caseName_h').val(). is the value of text field..

Comment: Now you can change my query>?

Comment: You shall not use queries inside javascript code. It's beyond any form of security, and especially when you insert "raw" data like that.
You'd better make an ajax post request to a php page which is gonna make the request for you with PDO for example

Comment: But  i am not using ajax i will show you my code..

Comment: I am using like this....please check my update .Is there any way to bot to user block to this character

Comment: can we use this var thisNotes = $('textarea#notes').val().replace(/(["'])/g,'&quot;');

Comment: I know this kind of comment is not helping you to solve your main problem. But I stand still : you should not use Javascript for a database system. Javascript is *client-side* so it's changeable at any time by any hacker, or just a competent person.
Rohit's solution is good, replacing datas into html entities.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like **encodeURIComponent("The special characters.")**,

This helps you to allow all special characters.

Comment: But this is my querry in phonegap.tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');